# How to configure sibling libraries?

Tags: meson-build

I have a library project (with more to be added later) and "common code" split out into its own project.  So the directory looks like:

- topdir

  - CommonLib
  - Lib1
  - Lib2

CommonLib and Lib1 are separate git repos.  I don't want any controlled files in topdir itself.

How do I make mason.build files so that Lib1 is dependent on CommonLib?  Both sets of files are being edited at the same time, so it's not like a specific version of a dependency that is installed first.

Answer (score 0):

[`declare_dependency()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#declare_dependency)'s main use is exactly this.

e.g.

```
CommonLib_headers = include_directories('CommonLib/include/')
CommonLib = library('commonlib', include_directories: CommonLib_headers)
dep_CommonLib = declare_dependency(link_with: CommonLib, include_directories: CommonLib_headers)

Lib1 = library('lib1', lib1_sourcefiles, dependencies: [dep_CommonLib])
```

---

- `CommonLib_headers`

  - represents headers needed to interact with the CommonLib library, e.g. function prototypes
- `CommonLib`

  - represents the actual CommonLib library (in meson this is called a **buildtarget**)
- `dep_CommonLib`

  - represents CommonLib as a dependency to other targets in the project, you can think of this as "everything that's needed for another target to make use of CommonLib" -- in this case it's, well, the actual library CommonLib that needs to be built, and its header files

---

Note that linking, for example, executables with the `Lib1` build object won't automagically link them against `CommonLib` as well, you have to specify that manually.

In other words, making `dep_CommonLib` a dependency of `Lib1` is like saying: "if any component specified by `dep_CommonLib` changes, also rebuild Lib1 accordingly".